# What is the difference between 'keys.each' and 'each_key'?

Tags: ruby, performance

When iterating through a hash like below:

```
hash.keys.each do |key|
  process_key(key)
end
```

Rubocop proclaims I should use:

```
each_key
```

instead of:

```
keys.each
```

What is the "key" difference between `keys.each` and `each_key`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rubocop wants you to follow this based on your evaluated code due to performance. Using large sets of data is where this becomes noticeable. Here's the doc on it: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/manual/cops_performance.md#performancehasheachmethods

I also found a benchmark someone wrote up to test this: https://gist.github.com/jodosha/8ca2bee6137be94e9dcb

I modified it a bit and ran it on on of my systems:

```
Warming up --------------------------------------
         string each   128.742k i/100ms
         string keys   114.523k i/100ms
     string each_key   134.279k i/100ms
         symbol each   128.838k i/100ms
         symbol keys   109.398k i/100ms
     symbol each_key   132.021k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
         string each      2.053M (± 4.0%) i/s -     10.299M in   5.026890s
         string keys      1.864M (± 1.4%) i/s -      9.391M in   5.039759s
     string each_key      2.224M (± 5.5%) i/s -     11.145M in   5.032201s
         symbol each      2.082M (± 1.0%) i/s -     10.436M in   5.013145s
         symbol keys      1.815M (± 2.1%) i/s -      9.080M in   5.004690s
     symbol each_key      2.240M (± 1.9%) i/s -     11.222M in   5.012184s

Comparison:
     symbol each_key:  2239720.0 i/s
     string each_key:  2224205.1 i/s - same-ish: difference falls within error
         symbol each:  2081895.2 i/s - 1.08x  slower
         string each:  2052884.9 i/s - 1.09x  slower
         string keys:  1863740.5 i/s - 1.20x  slower
         symbol keys:  1815131.1 i/s - 1.23x  slower
```

Chaining methods is going to be slower than using the built-in method (in this case) which accomplishes the task with a single special enumerator. The language creators put it there for a reason, also its idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

Rubocop is wrong. Which one you should use depends on what you want as the return value.

1. If you want an array of the keys back, then you should use `keys.each`. `key` creates a new array of keys, and `each` returns that array of keys after performing the block on each key.
2. If you do not need to have an array of keys (and want the original hash back), then you should use `each_key` since that does not create an array that would not be used, and would be more efficient.

Comment: Rubocop is not wrong when applied to the posters implementation.

Comment: Thank you that explains it very well.

Comment: @sawa expanding on @ddubs answer, the return value of `each` is not being used, so `keys.each` creates a temporary array which is then discarded. `each_key` creates a lazy enumerator, which is more efficient for large hashes

Comment: @Max "the return value of each is not being used" -- Where does that come from? That is the whole issue, and you have not provided explanation to it.

Comment: The issue isn't the usage of the returned enumerator of `each` it is the unnecessary creation of the enumerator `keys` which then chains to another creation of an enumerator `each`. Why create the additional overhead when you can leverage a single special purpose enumerator. Its literally there for that exact reason!

Comment: @ddubs No, the returned value of `each` is not an enumerator in this case. It is the original hash. Again, why are you sure that the `keys` array is unnecessary?

Comment: `puts Hash.new({a:1, b:1, c:1}).keys.each { |i| }.class.name` returns `Array`.

Comment: @ddubs You are right this time, it returns an array. Not an enumerator as you wrote previously. Again again again, `why are you sure that the keys array is unnecessary?`

Comment: You stated that it returned the original hash, I was simply showing it doesn't. Its unnecessary because, as we've pointed out numerous times `each_key` does the work of what chaining `keys` and `each` does, but more efficiently.

Comment: @ddubs No, as I've pointed out numerous times, `each_key` does not return the array of keys, which `keys.each` does. `each_key` returns the original hash.